# Moq - Verify no methods were called except one

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a controller with a method that reads configuration to determine which other method(s) to call. Depending on the config, it may call zero, one, or all of the `WorkerMethodN()` methods.

```
public class MyController
{
   public virtual bool EntranceMethod()
   {
      // read configuration to determine which methods to call
   }

   public virtual void WorkerMethod1() { ... }
   public virtual void WorkerMethod2() { ... }
   public virtual void WorkerMethod3() { ... }
}
```

I am trying to test this `EntranceMethod()` and my first test is to determine behavior when the configuration is empty. When the configuration returns nothing, I want to ensure that none of the `WorkerMethodN()` methods are called.

My test so far:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldNotCallAnyMethodsWhenConfigurationReturnsNull()
{
   this.mockConfigurationReader
       .Setup(cr => cr.GetEnabledConfigurations())
       .Returns((IEnumerable<Configuration>)null);

   Mock<MyController> mockController =
      new Mock<MyController>(MockBehavior.Strict, this.mockConfigurationReader.Object);

   mockController.Object.EntranceMethod();

   // todo: verify no additional methods are called
}
```

This call fails with the Exception: `invocation failed with mock behavior Strict. All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.` when the call to `EntranceMethod()` is made.

How do I use `MockBehavior.Strict` and setup my controller to call `EntranceMethod()` and verify that no other methods are called? If I call `.Setup()` on my `EntranceMethod()`, it won't run the actual code I want it to. But if I don't call `.Setup()`, I get an exception.

Comment: Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: Remove `MockBehavior.Strict`, enable `CallBase = true` then setup and check the other methods were not called using `.Verify(......., Times.Never())`

Answer (score 0):

For demonstrative purposes only, assume the following

```
public class Configuration {

}

public interface IConfigurationReader {

    IEnumerable<Configuration> GetEnabledConfigurations();
}

public class MyController {
    private IConfigurationReader configReader;


    public MyController(IConfigurationReader configReader) {
        this.configReader = configReader;
    }

    public virtual bool EntranceMethod() {
        // read configuration to determine which methods to call
        var config = configReader.GetEnabledConfigurations();

        //...code for example purposes only
        if (config != null) {
            WorkerMethod1();
            WorkerMethod2();
            WorkerMethod3();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public virtual void WorkerMethod1() {
        //... 
    }
    public virtual void WorkerMethod2() {
        //... 
    }
    public virtual void WorkerMethod3() {
        //... 
    }
}
```

Remove `MockBehavior.Strict`, enable `CallBase = true` then setup and check the other methods were not called using `.Verify(......., Times.Never())`

```
[TestClass]
public class MyControllerTest {
    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldNotCallAnyMethodsWhenConfigurationReturnsNull() {
        //Arrange
        var mockConfigurationReader = new Mock<IConfigurationReader>();
        mockConfigurationReader
            .Setup(cr => cr.GetEnabledConfigurations())
            .Returns((IEnumerable<Configuration>)null);

        var mockController = new Mock<MyController>(mockConfigurationReader.Object) {
            CallBase = true
        };

        //Act
        mockController.Object.EntranceMethod();

        //Assert
        // todo: verify no additional methods are called
        mockController.Verify(_ => _.WorkerMethod1(), Times.Never());
        mockController.Verify(_ => _.WorkerMethod2(), Times.Never());
        mockController.Verify(_ => _.WorkerMethod3(), Times.Never());
    }
}
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

Answer (score 0):

### Modern answer (Moq 4.8 or later):

```
mock.Verify(...);
mock.VerifyNoOtherCalls();
```

That code does 2 things:

1. Verifies that any expected calls were made
2. Verifies that no other calls were made

Source: [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#verification)